# Object does not support property or method « _get_eventHandlerList »

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

i got this error while trying to rebind a grid:
(

Parent page ( where the grid is)

```
function refreshGrid(arg) {
    if (!arg) {
        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Rebind");
    }
} 


<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="500px" Title="Details du ticket"
            Skin="WebBlue" Behaviors="Close, Move" Modal="true">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

.CS:

```
    protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument == "Rebind")
        {
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
            RadGrid1.Rebind();
        }
    }
```

JS function in window( when i close it, i want the grid in parent page to be refreshed)

```
function CloseDialog(args) {
    GetRadWindow().close();
    GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.refreshGrid(args); 
    return true;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing all these, try this simple example:

In `radWindow` you will get one client event called `OnClientClose`, you can call that and rebind your grid easily. See below what i have done:

```
<telerik:RadWindow runat="server" Behaviors="Maximize,Close,Move" ID="editorWindow"
    VisibleStatusbar="false" Width="800px" ReloadOnShow="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
    OnClientClose="OnWindowClose" Modal="true" Height="500px" />
```

Here is the JS Function :

```
function OnWindowClose(sender, eventArgs) {
    var MasterTable = gridID.get_masterTableView();
    MasterTable.rebind();
}
```

**Note**: on `pageLoad` of parent page i have assigned the `gridID` like this `var gridID = $find('<%=radGrid.ClientID%>')`. You can also find/get the grid directly in `OnWindowClose` function, as my scenario was bit different.